# Что значит ERROR: check constraint is violated by some row

Tags: postgresql

Есть такая таблица:

```
CREATE TABLE table (
    array1 intereger[] NOT NULL,
    array2 intereger[] NOT NULL
)
```

Мне нужно добавить в неё такое ограничение:

```
ALTER TABLE table ADD CONSTRAINT contains_constraint CHECK (array1 <@ array2);
```

Но этот запрос выдает такую ошибку:

```
ERROR: check constraint "contains_constraint" is violated by some row
```

Что не так?

Comment: А какой смысл в таких вопросах-ответах. думаете они часто возникают, учитывая, что сообщение об ошибке точно описывает, что пошло не так

Comment: @Mike Я поискал по руSO - тут ни одного вопроса на тему `violated by some row` нет. Я думаю, кому то это поможет.

Comment: Обычно постгрес показывает, какие именно строчки виноваты. Невнятное "some row" скорее всего связано с отсутствием в таблице первичного ключа.

Comment: @Mike Вы заработали знак "популярный вопрос")

Comment: @Mike Вы заработали знак "Известный вопрос")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дело в том, что в таблице уже есть строки, которые нарушают данное ограничение. Перед тем как его добавить, их нужно найти и удалить.
Самый простой способ:

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE array1 <@ array2;
```